# Verify Linux FAT32 Support

Tags: debian, filesystems, vfat, fat32

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I could not find any related question.

**How can I verify that my Linux 3.16.1 kernel supports FAT32?**

---

Things to keep in mind:

I do not have `/proc/config.gz` available to me.  When I build the kernel I enabled the following config values:

```
# DOS/FAT/NT Filesystems
#
CONFIG_FAT_FS=y
CONFIG_MSDOS_FS=y
CONFIG_VFAT_FS=y
CONFIG_FAT_DEFAULT_CODEPAGE=437
CONFIG_FAT_DEFAULT_IOCHARSET="iso8859-1"
CONFIG_NTFS_FS=y
# CONFIG_NTFS_DEBUG is not set
# CONFIG_NTFS_RW is not set
```

However, when I plug in a USB drive formatted with FAT32 it is not automounted.  This is fine.  I'm not a complete Linux n00b.  I ran `lsusb`, and saw my device listed.  Fantastic!  Lets see what its listed under in `/dev`.  I ran `sudo blkid`, nothing but my HDD is the only disk listed.

Running `modprobe vfat` and restarting did not change the results from above.

Is there something else that I'm missing?

**Edit** 
Kernel Messages when a USB device is connected and disconnected.

```
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   20.164811] usb 2-1.8: new full-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   20.280044] usb 2-1.8: New USB device found, idVendor=0a5c, idProduct=5801
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   20.280055] usb 2-1.8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   20.280061] usb 2-1.8: Product: 5880
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   20.280067] usb 2-1.8: Manufacturer: Broadcom Corp
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   20.280072] usb 2-1.8: SerialNumber: 0123456789ABCD
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   20.280200] usb 2-1.8: config 0 descriptor??
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   24.792805] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   24.792812] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   24.924891] input: Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1/2-1.1:1.0/0003:046D:C03E.0001/input/input14
Dec 10 11:46:45 narrator kernel: [   24.925127] hid-generic 0003:046D:C03E.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Logitech USB-PS/2 Optical Mouse] on usb-0000:00:1d.0-1.1/input0
Dec 10 11:49:43 narrator kernel: [  209.720215] usb 2-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 4
```

/proc/filesystems:

```
$ cat /proc/filesystems 
nodev   sysfs
nodev   rootfs
nodev   ramfs
nodev   bdev
nodev   proc
nodev   cgroup
nodev   cpuset
nodev   tmpfs
nodev   devtmpfs
nodev   debugfs
nodev   securityfs
nodev   sockfs
nodev   pipefs
nodev   devpts
nodev   hugetlbfs
    vfat
    msdos
    ntfs
nodev   pstore
nodev   mqueue
    ext4
nodev   autofs
    ext2
nodev   binfmt_misc
    fuseblk
nodev   fuse
nodev   fusectl
```

Comment: Comparing to default options on my Ubuntu (`grep -e FAT -e MSDOS /boot/config-$(uname -r)`), the values agree, but I have one extra: `CONFIG_MSDOS_PARTITION=y`. That said, a lack of FAT32 support should not prevent it from listing the partition tables, and that may be related to this option.

Comment: Could I get away with rebuilding just the modules, or would a full rebuild of the kernel be necessary?

Comment: What's the output of dmesg(which prints kernel messages)?

Comment: If the device doesn't show up, then what filesystem it is formatted with doesn't enter the picture.  You seem to have a busted device or usb port.

Comment: @psusi I used an older kernel, and the device came up just fine.  Same laptop.  Same device.

Comment: Maybe you are plugging it into a usb3 port, and your first kernel doesn't have the usb3 driver?

Comment: If that bit of config is correct, `vfat` was built into the kernel -- it is not an (un)loadable module and therefore `modprobe vfat` won't do anything.  Also, calling `modprobe` *then restarting* is pointless in all cases.  A module won't be automatically loaded on reboot because of this.  Modprobe loads a module *now*, and it takes effect immediately.

Answer (score 2):

First check this  `cat /proc/filesystems`  if `vfat` is their or not.
and 
sounds silly but work many time use some guitool FS tools like `Gparted`  sometimes its easy to troubleshoot with them.

To inspect all filesystem modules Check here also `ls /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs`

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: vfat is not listed in the `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/fs`  Any reason why it wouldn't be when the `/proc/filesystems` show that there is support?